# TableView Delegate Messages Not Being Called

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

SOLVED: Not really a solution, but I just used a .xib rather than trying to use the storyboard thing. Whatever I was trying to do with the storyboard was somehow messing up the TableView delegate methods from being called. Thanks for all the insight you guys provided.

I have a UIViewController that contains a UITableView that should be populated by an array.
Unfortunately the UITableView does not get populated by the array (which is not empty).

My .h file:

```
@interface Directory : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate> {
NSArray *listData;
NSArray *savedListData;
MKMapView* mapUI;
UISearchBar* searchBar;
NSArray * originalListData;
UITableView* placeList;
DirInfoListing *infoInst;
NSString *searchInit;
NSString *openInit;
NSMutableArray *buildings;}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *listData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *savedListData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar* searchBar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView* placeList;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil list:    (NSArray*)array  mapView:(MKMapView*) map;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil list:(NSArray*)array  mapView:(MKMapView*) map search:(NSString*) ss;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil list: (NSArray*)array  mapView:(MKMapView*) map open:(NSString*) openTx;
-(void)doDBLoad;
@end
```

And relevant stuff from my .m file:

```
#import "Directory.h"

@interface Directory ()

@end

@implementation Directory
@synthesize listData, savedListData;
@synthesize searchBar;
@synthesize placeList;

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1; 
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"ListData count: %lu", (unsigned long)savedListData.count);
        //This returns a valid number of 74 items
    return [self.savedListData count];
}

/*
 * Populates the table with list data and provides title. AND DOES NOT GET CALLED
 */
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *tID = @"tablIDDirect";
    UITableViewCell *c = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tID];
     if(c == nil) {
        c = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tID];
    }

    NSInteger r = [indexPath row];
    if([self.listData objectAtIndex:r] != nil){
        c.textLabel.text = ((DBBuilding*)[self.savedListData objectAtIndex:r]).Name;
        c.detailTextLabel.text = ((DBBuilding*)[self.savedListData objectAtIndex:r]).Acronym;
    }
    c.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return c;
}

/*
 * Displays an entry according to the table selection and redirects the user to the     Directory Information Listing.
 */
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger r = [indexPath row];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if(infoInst != nil) {
        infoInst = nil;
    }
    infoInst = [[DirInfoListing alloc] initWithNibName:@"DirInfoListing" bundle:nil building:[self.savedListData objectAtIndex:r] map:mapUI];
}

/*
 * Notification that the Directory is the active view
 */

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if(openInit != nil)
    {
        [self openEntry:openInit];
        openInit = nil;
    }

    placeList = [[UITableView alloc] init];

    placeList.dataSource = self;
    placeList.delegate = self;
    [placeList reloadData];
}

/*
 * Notification that the Directory is no longer the active view
 */

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"ListData count: %lu", (unsigned long)listData.count);
        //Also returns a valid number of 74 objects within the array
    savedListData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:listData];
        //That get put into another array just for my sanity

        [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    searchBar.text = searchInit;
    [self performSearch:searchInit];    
 }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

The `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`method gets called, but none of the other UITableView delegate methods are called and I am at a loss as to why this happens.

Also, this whole chunk of code is pulled from another one of my apps (That works correctly) using .xibs and DOES NOT use storyboards. This app (the one I'm having problems with) uses storyboards, which I am not very familiar with. I may be doing something wrong with calling and using the storyboard, but I am just not sure. If there may be something related to that I can provide more information.

Could you guys please go over my code and maybe see where I've gone wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an `@synthesize` line for `savedListData` in your .m? If so, please show it. If you don't, just say so.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the top part of the .m file

Comment: Are you using storyboards? If so, did you connect the UITableView delegate and datasource to the View Controller?

Comment: @Jon Yes, I am using storyboards (and I've never worked with them before so I might be doing something terribly wrong related to them) but my dataSource and delegate are connected to the TableView within the view controller, should they be connected to the view itself?

Comment: The data source and delegate should be connected to the controller (Directory). Did you put a log as the first line of cellForRowAtIndexPath, not inside the if clause to see if that method is being called? I don't see how it could not be, if numberOfSections and numberOfRows are both called, and return valid numbers.

Comment: @VonKnoob, Within the Storyboard, click the UITableView and hold the control key (A blue line should appear). Then, drag the connection to the view controller (The orange/yellow circle beside First Responder). A black selection box will appear, select datasource. Then, repeat these steps and select delegate.Also, make sure that the View Controller is set to the correct file. You can do this by going to the Identity Inspector and under Custom Class type in the name of your View Controller class name.

Comment: @rdelmar Both the dataSource and the delegate were connected to the controller, and that was my entire problem, the numberOfSections and numberOfRows were both called, but cellForRowAtIndexPath and other delegate methods were not called when I was using the storyboard (but not when using a .xib).

Comment: @Jon Thanks for your suggestions, but I had already done all of the things you presented, the View Controller was correctly set through the identity inspector. For whatever reason, the TableView delegate methods were not called when I was using a storyboard but worked perfectly fine when I took the .xib out of the storyboard and used it as a standalone file.

Comment: Hmm..., I just don't see how that's possible. If it calls the two data source methods I mentioned, and they both return non-zero value, cellForRowAtIndexPath should be called. Can you post the project on Github, or somewhere where we could actually look at it?

Comment: @rdelmar I couldn't see how that was possible either, but no I am not able to post the project on Github since it is not mine to distribute openly. Thanks for all your suggestions and hopefully I have no further problems related to the storyboard/xib and delegate methods issue I was having.

Answer (score 0):

In your "`viewDidLoad`" method, change one line to this:

```
self.savedListData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:listData];
```

Except "`listData`" needs to *be* something.  "`self.listData`" might be that something, but on my first pass, I do not see where "`self.listData`" gets populated or set.

With properties, you usually use "`self.`" to access (set and get) everything for the properties *everywhere* except in the `init` methods.

The reason the table is not displaying anything is because your "`numberOfRowsInSection`" method is likely returning zero.  Set a breakpoint and check that.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried that but the other delegate methods were still not called. The listData is populated by the previous viewController, but when I NSLog the listData it returns the array

Comment: The reason the other delegate methods aren't being called is because the "`numberOfRowsInSection`" method is returning zero. Use the Xcode debugger and step through that method and make certain everything is not null and returning a valid number, and once it's non-zero, the other delegate methods should start getting called.

Comment: That is exactly why I am confused, the "`numberofRowsInSection`" method DOES return a valid number.

Comment: what is the valid number?  is it the count of the number of entries in the array?  if you set a debugger breakpoint at the beginning of "`cellForRowAtIndexPath`", does it hit?

Comment: The valid number is 74, the number of entries in the array (should it not be returning the `[self.savedListData count]`"?). A breakpoint placed at the beginning of "`cellForRowAtIndexPath`" does not get hit.

Comment: One thing to rule out here: Override and implement ["`numberOfSectionsInTableView:`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/numberOfSectionsInTableView:) in your .m file and make sure you're returning exactly one (for one section).

Comment: Ahhhh, you might be onto something there, the "`numberOfSectionInTableView:`" returns 0, not one.

Comment: An oddity that I found while comparing two of my projects (The code I have presented here is from another, working app). When I add the "`numberOfSectionsInTableView:`" method to my previously existing app, it returns 0 and DOES NOT populate the table. However, when I do not include the "`numberOfSectionsInTableView:`" method, the table IS populated (despite the sections most likely being 0)

Comment: @VonKoob, no, the default is 1 if you don't implement numberOfSectionsInTAbleView.

Comment: @rdelmar So if I did not implement "`numberOfSectionsInTableView`", it would return 1? Then why does it return 0 when I include it?

Comment: @VonKoob What are you returning?

Comment: I do not believe I ever set the number of sections and I assumed it defaulted to 1. When I include that method though, it returns 0.

Comment: @VonKoob, What code do you have in the method? The boilerplate code that comes with the table view controller returns 0 and has a warning attached to it.

Comment: Just a simple "`return [self.listData count];`"

Comment: @VonKoob, and if you log [self.listData count] what does it give you? 0?

Comment: My mistake, it is actually [self.placeList numberOfSections], and both my apps (the working one and nonworking one) return 0. However, the working app fails to work when I include that method, for whatever reason.

Comment: @VonKoob, I'm not sure I understand. Are returning  [self.placeList numberOfSections]? If so, that's just wrong. If you want multiple sections, you have to return a count of something in your model. If you want one section, just don't implement the method, or do implement it and return 1.

Comment: @rdelmar Ah, well I have the "`numberOfSectionsInTableView`" returning 1. But I'm still back at my original issue of the other tableview delegate methods not being called.

Comment: @VonKoob, you should update your question with the code you now have in there, and include logs in the data source methods, and what they each give you.

Comment: @rdelmar, I have edited my question and code to reflect the changes I've made (which is just putting some logs in there and saying what they return).

Comment: @VonKoob if you're having a new problem you should create a brand new question. I hope I was able to help you out with solving your original problem.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann No, I am not having a different problem, your suggestions were helpful in determining what wasn't the problem. I still have my original problem of having only 1 of the delegate methods called and not the rest.